# Javafx change font color of filtered list in tableview

Tags: javafx, colors, tableview

I have a tableview named as tablesettings (@FXML TableView tablesettings)

And I have textfield that search value from tableview.

But I want to change font color of searhed matched text on tableview.

Simple code

```
       String sDriverName = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
        try {
            Class.forName(sDriverName);
            String sTempDb = "systemnet.db";
            String sJdbc = "jdbc:sqlite";
            String sDbUrl = sJdbc + ":" + sTempDb;
             // create a database connection
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sDbUrl);
            try {
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                try {

                     try {            
          connected();
             data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from Belgiler");
              while (rs.next()) {
                data.add(new form1Controller.userdata(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4)));
              }
             cid.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("id"));
             ctwo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("two"));
             csec.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("sec"));
             ctri.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("tri"));
              tablesettings.setItems(null);
              tablesettings.setItems(data);
              tablesettings.setEditable(true);
            closed();
        } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Error on Building Data"+ e.toString());

        }

                } finally {
                    try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
                }
            } finally {
                try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
            }
        }   catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(form1Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


       FilteredList<userdata> filt = new FilteredList<>(data, p ->true);
            textfield1.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { 
            filt.setPredicate(userdata -> {
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }  
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
           if (userdata.two.toString().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
               return true; // change font color
                } else if (userdata.sec.toString().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                    return true; 
                }
                return false; // Does not match.
            });SortedList<userdata> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filt);
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tablesettings.comparatorProperty());
        tablesettings.setItems(sortedData);
        });
```

Comment: BTW, when you post a question, try as much as is feasible to make your code example complete, but always make it minimal. For example, the database code is completely irrelevant to this question and just serves to distract from what you are asking. Making it easier to read and understand your question will in general help in getting it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom `TableCell` that observes the search text property, and uses a `TextFlow` for its graphic instead of plain text. When either the search text property changes, or from the `updateItem(...)` method, find the occurrence of the search text in the item and build the text flow out of chunks so you can highlight the appropriate chunk.

Here is a simple example that only highlights the first occurrence of the text; you can modify it to highlight all occurrences if you prefer:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;

public class HighlightingTableCell<S> extends TableCell<S, String> {

    private final ObservableValue<String> highlightText ;

    private final TextFlow textFlow ;

    public HighlightingTableCell(ObservableValue<String> highlightText) {
        this.highlightText = highlightText ;
        this.textFlow = new TextFlow() ;
        textFlow.setPrefHeight(12);

        highlightText.addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
            updateTextFlow(newText);
        });

        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            updateTextFlow(highlightText.getValue());
            setGraphic(textFlow);
        }
    }


    private void updateTextFlow(String highlight) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return ;
        }

        String item = getItem();
        int index = item.indexOf(highlight);

        if (highlight.isEmpty() || index < 0) {
            Text text = new Text(item);
            textFlow.getChildren().setAll(text);
            return ;
        }

        Text prior = new Text(item.substring(0, index));
        Text highlighted = new Text(item.substring(index, index+highlight.length()));
        highlighted.getStyleClass().add("highlight");
        Text post = new Text(item.substring(index+highlight.length()));     
        textFlow.getChildren().setAll(prior, highlighted, post);

    }


}
```

and here's a quick test case:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HighlightingFilteredTable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

        TextField searchField = new TextField();
        searchField.setPromptText("Enter filter text");

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        firstNameColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new HighlightingTableCell<>(searchField.textProperty()));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
        lastNameColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new HighlightingTableCell<>(searchField.textProperty()));

        table.getColumns().add(firstNameColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(lastNameColumn);

        ObservableList<Person> allData= FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown")
        );

        FilteredList<Person> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(allData);
        filteredList.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
            person -> person.getFirstName().contains(searchField.getText()) || person.getLastName().contains(searchField.getText()), 
            searchField.textProperty()));

        table.setItems(filteredList);

        BorderPane.setMargin(searchField, new Insets(5));
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table,searchField, null, null, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }


        public final String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }


        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }


        public final String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setLastName(final String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with style.css:

```css
.table-cell .highlight {
    -fx-fill: red ;
}
```

Comment: One more question. Can I set text align to center?

Comment: worked fine but cell background turning black.

Comment: @NoorHossain I just ran the example posted here, and the cell background was not turning black.